# FirebaseUI with dependency injection

Tags: android, firebase, dependency-injection, dagger-2, firebaseui

I am using dagger for dependency injection, and all my activities are dagger injected:

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {    
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

So when I use FirebaseUI, I understandably get the error for FirebaseUI activities

> No injector factory bound for Class < com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity >

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines to your activity module class.

```
  @PerActivity
  @ContributesAndroidInjector
  internal abstract fun contributeKickoffActivity(): KickoffActivity

  @PerActivity
  @ContributesAndroidInjector
  internal abstract fun contributeAuthMethodPickerActivity(): AuthMethodPickerActivity
```